# How to install OpenCv 3.1.0 without root permissions ?

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, installation

I downloaded the OpenCv 3.1.0 package and I would like to install it on Ubuntu 16.04. I am not sudo on my computer and I wanted to know how to install correctly OpenCV locally.

Answer (score 5):

You can install OpenCV to any folder that you have write permission with `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` flag, whose default is `/usr/local`. For example:

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX='/home/username/local' ..
make -j8 && make install
```

Since header files and libraries are not install in system path, you have to configure your OpenCV projects manually.

Comment: Normally, OpenCV people execute `cmake` command in the build directory. See the edit for the extra command.

Comment: Excuse me I was wrong to order. That's ok it works. Thank you

Comment: Excuse me but I have an error with make -j8 && make install this error is :  recipe for target 'modules/cudaimgproc/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_gftt.cu.o' failed
make[2]: *** [modules/cudaimgproc/CMakeFiles/cuda_compile.dir/src/cuda/cuda_compile_generated_gftt.cu.o] Error 1

Comment: looks like a CUDA problem. I've encountered several incompatibilities between CUDA, gcc, and OpenCV. If you don't need CUDA, you can disable it with flag `WITH_CUDA=OFF`.

Comment: Excuse me but where I have to put flag WITH_CUDA=OFF because it does not work

Comment: `cmake -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX='/home/username/local' -D WITH_CUDA=OFF ..`. You should do a `rm -rf *` in the build directory first.

Comment: Ok it works I added cmake -D BUILD_opencv_gpu=OFF -D WITH_CUDA=OFF CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX='/home/username/local' .. Thank you. have a good day